# make background go fullscreen

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like my silverlight background to be fullscreen. Now, i am setting my background as :

```
<Grid.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="/_Assets/Layout/family-tree-bg.jpg"/>
  </Grid.Background>
```

but there is still the black bar that holds the battery, clock, signal etc. How can my background cover this zone also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an System Tray transparent: (work for WP 7.5 only)

```
 shell:SystemTray.Opacity="0"
```

Or just make it invisible:

```
 shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
```